# Formulating hypothesys on continuous and categorial variables independence

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons

Consider following process. We have $k$ people. They commit actions and we write down time of these actions in common list.

We want to test the hypothesis that time of events is independent with who produces the event.

The problem I am stuck with is all methods I know work with continuous or with categorial variables. Here we have both of them. What statistical procedure can be conducted?